# Error: Main method not found

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, program-entry-point

```
Error: main method not found in class essence.Game, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)
```

The code:

```
package essence;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import org.lwjgl.input.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

public class Game{

    List<Box> shapes = new ArrayList<Box>(16);

    public Game(){
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.setTitle("Essence");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        shapes.add(new Box(15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Box(100, 150));

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(0);
            }

            for (Box box : shapes) {
                box.draw();
            }

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private static class Box {
        public boolean selected = false;
        public int x, y;
        private float colorRed, colorBlue, colorGreen;

        Box (int x, int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();

            colorRed = randomGenerator.nextFloat();
            colorBlue = randomGenerator.nextFloat();
            colorGreen = randomGenerator.nextFloat();   
        }

        boolean inBounds(int mouseX, int mouseY){
            if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x + 50 && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + 50)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        void randomizeColors(){
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();

            colorRed = randomGenerator.nextFloat();
            colorBlue = randomGenerator.nextFloat();
            colorGreen = randomGenerator.nextFloat();   
        }

        void update(int dx, int dy){
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }

        void draw(){
            glColor3f(colorRed, colorGreen, colorBlue);

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glVertex2f(x + 50, y);
            glVertex2f(x + 50, y + 50);
            glVertex2f(x, y + 50);
            glEnd();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           new Game();
    }
}
```

Now let's say I change it to:

```
package essence;

public class Game{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

It will still give the same error. I checked the folder layout, but I confirmed that its `Eclipse\Data\workspace\Essence\src\essence` and `Eclipse\Data\workspace\Essence\bin\essence`

It cannot be my Java installation, because all my other projects work fine. Here's a screenshot of the project within Eclipse:

http://gyazo.com/296d53b33fa2619ca300c8a896d097dc

What could be the cause of this error and the way to fix it?

Comment: Where and how are you trying to run it?

Comment: try adding a deliberate syntax error to your class and redo your compilation/invocation.   I bet you won't get a syntax error message from the compiler.  This means you environment is picking up an older version of the compiled class located elsewhere on your system.

Comment: `ctrl+F11` doesn't work, and I'm trying to run it within eclipse using `play` button. Cleaning the project has no effect.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky I still get `Error: Could not find or load main class essence.Game` if I type `lol` at random places. I have removed the .launch files. The bin folder is empty. There is just one weird thing, when running it asked my wether to run `Game` or `Game(1)`, don't know if that matters?

Comment: try running game(1).  eclipse thinks you have two Game classes, so it appends (1) to the second one.  The classes may or may not be in different projects.  In any case, it's reading the wrong one.  If that doesnt work, you may need to swap workspaces and back again, or clear some cache, or something like that

Comment: For some reason after restarting eclipse the option for running `Game(1)` is gone. Any ideas left?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me as well. Restarting the Compiler fix the problem. For Example, If you are running Eclipse, just restart Eclipse.